# Auto-focus is on, but zoom is locked using Android Camera2 API, why is the image getting scaled?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I have created an android camera app, where I've used Camera2API, the zoom is locked and the auto-focus feature is turned on. However the camera-preview shows a weird zooming artifact. See the video link below:
https://youtu.be/NSg2yV3xHv8

I've tried to research online about smartphone camera lenses and from what I understand the camera-lens focal length is fixed. If the focal length is fixed and the zoom is turned off, why should the depth of the image preview be changing?

Phone I am using is OnePlus-7T. Also have tried implementing the same with Android CameraX API.

Would be grateful for any answers as to why this could be happening? Is the camera focal responsible for this.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the camera trying to autofocus, but failing to lock on to a stable focus distance.

Because of the way lens optics work, changing focus distance slightly changes the camera field of view as well, resulting in the effect you see.

I'm not sure why you're seeing difficulty with focus - which focus mode are you using, and are you using the AF_TRIGGER control? Or just leaving it on continuous focus?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is setting the AF to a fixed 100x100 region in the center of preview: `val action = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point).build(); camera.cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(action);` 

This is how I have fixed the focus region using CameraX API. However this is only triggered on touch to focus, initially it is on continuous focus. I believe this triggers it using Camera2 as follows: `mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);`

Comment: Also, you say changing focus distance slightly changes the camera FOV. Does this mean the focal length is changing as well when we try to focus on different regions? However in the image EXIF data focal length is always fixed.

Comment: Generally, the small amount of focus breathing is not accounted for in the focal length reporting. Especially for fixed-focal-length cameras.

Comment: Also, does the focus and metering action complete? It doesn't seem from the video that it does.  Might you be restarting it repeatedly?